# Text View inside of Table View Dynamic Cells produces weird scrolling behavior

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uikit, tableview

When typing into a UITextView inside of a Dynamic Cell AND the enclosing Table View has been scrolled down so that the UITextView/Cell currently being edited IS NOT VISIBLE on the screen, the table view scrolls weird, i.e. pops up or down a screen, and the section headers move visually INTO the cell areas.

I've messed with this for a few months and have not been able to fix all the issues. I'm using AutoLayout and UITableView.automaticDimensions to calculate a dynamic cell height. Then using beginUpdates() and endUpdates() within cellForRowAt to dynamically animate and update the size of each table view cell.

It's also worth mentioning I have a non-scrollable UITextView inside EVERY cell.

I've tried to disable scrolling of the table view; tried to reset the scroll position of the table view; and nothing seems to work. UIKit seems very buggy.

```
override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        localModel = TPClass.sharedInstance.theTomorrowPlanModel
        //self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 512
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        //self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTomorrowCell", for: indexPath) as! TextViewTableViewCell

        // call back from cell
        cell.textChanged {[weak tableView, weak self] newText in
        TPClass.sharedInstance.theTomorrowPlanModel.dataArray[indexPath.section].text = newText

            // update model
            self?.localModel.dataArray[indexPath.section].text = newText

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("This is run on the main queue")
                self?.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
                self?.currentScrollPos = self?.tableView.contentOffset.y
                tableView?.beginUpdates()
                tableView?.endUpdates()
                self?.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
                self?.currentScrollPos = nil
            }


        } // end call back

        cell.textView.text = localModel.dataArray[indexPath.section].text
        return cell

    }

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Force the tableView to stay at scroll position until animation completes
        if (currentScrollPos != nil){
            tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: currentScrollPos!), animated: false)
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, I can tell you that UIKit is not buggy :). Second if you can upload storyboard or capture of the issue in gif or something. It would be much better to understand your problem. And it is not good idea to manually adjust scroll positions.

Comment: One way I can think right now is do not try to edit text in the cell, instead try to have a another textview as hidden and show when user tap on one of the textview in the cell and show it on top of tableview and hide again when editing is finished or you can navigate to edit view controller and come back. So textview in the cell only display its contents.